# Asynchronous request crawling using Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, pyquery

I want to crawl the link:
http://data.eastmoney.com/hsgt/index.html

But I found the XHR documents are all without data, but EventSteam, so how can I crawl the complete information of the page.

For example, I want to crawl -94.67亿元 on the page.

my code is below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pyquery import PyQuery
from lxml import etree
import time

response = requests.get(url='http://data.eastmoney.com/hsgt/index.html',
                        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'})
response.encoding = 'GB2312'

# this shows False
'-94.67' in response.text
```

**I then try to install dryscape but failed, it said I have no web server file.**

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: I've add some code for your reference

Answer (score 2):

As you mention the XHR requests, managed by the javascript running in the client, aren't being executed. This is down to the fact that the requests` package doesn't execute javascript and isn't trying to mimic a web browser. You should look into an alternative approach. There are quite a lot. You have many options, and I'd suggest you reading pages like [the following](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f) for more context on the problem.

And, additionally, maybe look at something like [dryscrape](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I haven't used it myself, by it seems like something akin to this

```
import dryscrape

sess = dryscrape.Session()
sess.visit('http://data.eastmoney.com/hsgt/index.html')
source = sess.body()
```

is what you are after. Have fun.